# How to add facts to JESS working memory when a event happend out of Jess

Tags: rule-engine, jess, fact

How can I do to add new dynamic facts to working memory?
for Example:
If I have a rule like this:

```
(deftemplate person(slot idPerson)(slot age)(slot like))

(defrule sports
"Give a discount on sport items"
(person {age >18 && age<30}{like soccer}{idPerson ?idPerson})
=>
(add (new offer"10% of discount on sport items to" ?idPerson)))
```

And.. If Jess is running until there are rule to fire.(run-until-halt)

How can I do to add new facts to Jess working memory from another 
application or script when a event happend out of Jess?

Comment: If you run Jess from a Java application by calling the Rete method runUntilHalt in one thread, you can use Rete methods add and addAll to insert new facts from another thread.